# Is Type Casting possible without a Conversion Constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

For a user defined class which already has an explicit constructor accepting a single argument, Is it possible to implement the Conversion Constructor behavior in some other way.

The class in question -

```
class Foo
{
    explicit Foo(int size);
}
```

Is it possible to make this code still valid -

```
Foo a = 3;
```

Comment: No. Either make the constructor non-`explicit`, or you'll have to write `Foo a(3);` or `Foo a = Foo(3);`

Comment: Why do you need another way? Just use what the language can already do.

Comment: @The Pc Luddite The constructor is already in use for other purposes..

Comment: @g6799821 An implicit constructor can be used both implicitly and explicitly, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't just make it non-explicit.

Comment: @The Pc Luddite Consider the class Foo represents an array of int. The constructor with an int can be used to set the size of the array. In that case, its already in use for a different prupose.

Comment: @g6799821 Okay, but if you don't declare that constructor `explicit`, you can use it like this `Foo a(3)` or like this `Foo a = 3`. You can use it explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: @The Pc Luddite Wouldn't that make it unsafe ?
Also in that case Foo a=3 would just represent an empty array of 3 size. The desired behavior is that, Foo a =3 would create an array with the first element's value set to 3. This is not a very good example, but I just want to know if its possible to implement.

Comment: @g6799821 C++ isn't a "safe" language, so you can do a lot of things that are unsafe. Anyway, it's probably a bad design choice if you think that you need two constructors with the same argument for two separate purposes.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. A constructor can only be used for one purpose, and you can't have two constructors with the same arguments that do different things.

If `Foo` were an array of `int`s like you said in your comments, it probably would be a poor design choice to have a constructor with a single argument that fills the first element of the array. It's poor design for a couple of reasons:

1. How do you know what size the array is going to be when `Foo` is initialized? Even if there were some default value, it would be a non-obvious implementation.
2. It's confusing. You should use the [element of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) when designing code. I've never, ever seen a class that wraps an array have a single argument constructor that fills it's first element. It doesn't really make sense.

In C++ 11, you can use an initializer list as the second constructor.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cstring>

class Foo {
    private:
        int* arr;
        size_t len;
    public:
        explicit Foo(size_t size)
            : len(size) {
            arr = new int[len];
        }

        Foo(std::initializer_list<int> list) // Initializer list constructor
            : len(list.size()) {
            arr = new int[len];
            size_t pos = 0;
            for(auto it = list.begin(), e = list.end(); it != e; ++it) {
                arr[pos++] = *it; // copy the list into your array
            }
        }

        Foo(const Foo& other) 
           : len(other.len) {
             arr = new int[len];
             memcpy(arr, other.arr, len * sizeof*arr);
        }

        Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) {
              if (&other != this) {
                   delete[] arr;
                   len = other.len;
                   arr = new int[len];
                   memcpy(arr, other.arr, len * sizeof*arr);
              }
              return *this;
        }

        ~Foo() {
            delete[] arr;
        }
};
```

That way, you could use it like this to initialize 1 element:

```
 Foo a = { 3 };
```

Or like this to create an array with "3" ints:

```
 Foo a(3);
```

Or even create the whole array at once:

```
 Foo a = { 3, 7, 10, 12, 13 };
```

I realize that you just used an int-array as an example, but this just shows that there are often better ways of designing code then what you propose.

Answer (score -4):

Yes.  Right after the definition of `class Foo` simply write:

```
struct Bar {
  Bar(int){};
};
#define Foo Bar
```

and the required code now compiles, and calls a conversion constructor.

This seems like a bad idea, but it is possible.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to do. `Foo` is a class that needs to be initialized with a value of `5`. The OP doesn't need another alias for `int`.

Comment: The OP asked if `Foo a = 3` could be valid: the above makes it valid.  Pointlessly, but that is a provlem with the question.  It is possible with an `explicit Foo(int)` to make `Foo f=5;` compile.

Comment: @Yakk7 He asked if `Foo a = 3` could be valid in the context of a "conversion constructor". This is not a constructor. It's a macro.

Comment: True, I should have `#define Foo Bar`, then added a `struct Bar` with a conversion constructor.  Thanks!